# Getting all lines by author per file in git

Tags: bash, git, shell, gitlab, git-blame

I want to get all authors that contributed to a file (working). Additionally I want the number of lines from each author of a file (working). And in the end I also want each line number that was contributed by each author. The format should not be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14 but instead be something like 1-5, 11-14. Is that doable in an "easy" way on the command line? I can't do anything by hand as we have thousands of files with around 2 million lines of code.

```
files=$(git ls-tree -r HEAD | cut -c54-)
for file in $files
do
        echo $file
        git blame $file --line-porcelain | grep  "^author " | sort | uniq -c | sort -r
done
```

is doing what i want besides the line numbers.

Comment: okay, so, what, you want someone to show you how to postprocess `git blame | cat -n`?

Comment: No, an easy way. So something that already can do it without doing a lot of programming. Maybe an option in one of the git commands.

But maybe I understood in the wrong way as I can't see a benefit in using cat -n. Numbered lines I already get with git blame. If I do any post processing I probably will use this output directly.